# Neo4j 3.2 Grass file no longer in favorites menu?

Tags: neo4j

I'm using the latest version of Neo4j, v 3.2.0 -the GRASS style sheet was earlier available in the Favorites menu of the browser, but it seems to have disappeared from this location. Please advise if you know the location/how to access it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was running into the same problem, so it seems to be a bug with this new version. I could not find the path, where it is located, but I solved my issue with this temporary workaround:

1) I uploaded the `grass.css` to a server, e.g. [http://gist.github.com](https://gist.github.com/nicho90/7813e4cb7c0ff3948ed540bc4278f2da)

2) Opened the Neo4j-browser again and run the following Cypher query:

```
:style https://gist.githubusercontent.com/.../grass.css
```

I hope it will help you too until the bug will be fixed.

Comment: Where did you get the grass.css - Could I take a grass.css from a previous version? Also, it is interesting that this is the way to use a custom grass.css file:)

Comment: I created one, but you can also use a previous one. The structure is very simple, you can find my file here: [https://gist.github.com/nicho90/7813e4cb7c0ff3948ed540bc4278f2da](https://gist.github.com/nicho90/7813e4cb7c0ff3948ed540bc4278f2da)

Comment: Btw. I assigned an issue to that ([https://github.com/neo4j/neo4j-browser/issues/533](https://github.com/neo4j/neo4j-browser/issues/533)). I'm sure it will be fixed soon.

Comment: The bug has been fixed in v3.2.1! I used a .css file for the styles, so that I got code highlighting in my IDE, but the data format should be .grass, so don't forget to rename it, before you import it to Neo4j ;)